# Setting high tx fees (paytxfee, maxtxfee,..)

Tags: transaction-fees

I am building different tx types on regtest and don't want to care about tx fees.

Here is my bitcoin.config

*fallbackfee=100000
paytxfee=100000
maxtxfee=100000
mintxfee=0.1
maxfeerate=100000*

I have set the values absurdly high, but bitcoin core still doesn't allow to send a transaction (P2WPKH, 1 input and 1 output) with 100 btc in fees, and still get

*Fee exceeds maximum configured by user (e.g. -maxtxfee, maxfeerate) (code -25)*

Answer (score 2):

Solved. Despite definition in bitcoin.config, when calling sendrawtransaction we need to pass again the maxfeerate

sendrawtransaction raw_tx_hex 1000

Comment: `maxtxfee` is a *wallet* configuration option; it doesn't apply to `sendrawtransaction` as that isn't a wallet RPC.